# Linear transformation on v.s. of polynomial. Show Relation of Kernel, Image, minimal polynomial, direct sum and eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve the following 4 part problem:

Let $V$ = $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ be the vector space of all polynomial of three variables with complex koefficients.

We define an operator $L$ on $V$ by

$$L(f(x,y,z)) = \frac{f(x,y,z)+f(y,z,x)+f(z,x,y)}{3}$$
for all $f(x,y,z) \in V$

Let $K$ = ker($L$),  $W$ = im($L$) and $V_2$ subspace of V containing polynomials of degree 2 and lower.

1) Show that $q_L(x) = x^2-x$ is the minimal polynomial for the operator L

2) Show that $V = K \oplus W$ as an inner direct sum

3) Show that $V/ K \cong W$ and $V/W \cong K$

4) Show that $K$ and $W$ are eigenspaces for the operator $L$ and find bases 
for these eigenspaces intersection with $V_2$

I'm really lost, this is what I got.

1. We need to show that $q_L(x) = x^2-x$ is the monic polynomial of smallest degree that satisfies several properties.
2. Internal direct sum is defined as follows : 
   Suppose that $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that any vector $v\in V$ can uniquely be decomposed as $v=w_1+w_2$.

Using the definition of kernel, we multiply by 3 and rewrite K as follows :

$K = ker(L)={\{f(x,y,z) : f(x,y,z) = -f(y,z,x)-f(z,x,y)}\}$

Furthermore, is image the same as range in this instance? If so, we have

$W = range(L)={\{ L(f(x,y,z)) : f(x,y,z)\in V}\} $

Now we somehow need to show that the subspaces $K$ and $W$ are big enough, that the decomposition as described is unique and that the intersection of $K$ and $W$ is ${0}$?

Any help/solutions/tips with this would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks beforehand